# Getting error while setting up the SetIntializer method in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting the error below while trying to run the code. I'm following tutorial from Youtube to learn ASP.NET MVC:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lrr66APUwBk&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v&index=8&t=646s

I'm trying to add the database so that I can use this for first time. I'm new to C#, please help me so that I can solve this error.

[image]

Comment: Does the EmployeeContext Class inherit DbContext ?

Comment: yes


namespace WBC.Models
{
    public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: Right click on DbContext and 'Go to Definition'.  What assembly is being referenced at the top of the class? `Assembly EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0`?